# Debugging Optimistic Concurrency with AJAX Call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, concurrency

I'm currently having a problem with optimistic concurrency in my ASP.NET MVC application.

Essentially, this following controller works fine when called upon once. However, I have a page that is made to modify residents in six different groups at the same time. This is where the problem occurs. Basically, I post up the list of residents one at a time for each list so there are essentially six concurrent ajax calls that hit the server at the same time. (This may be what I need to change, but I am not sure!)

The javascript ajax call posts up the id of the group along with a list of the resident IDs. The residents are then added to the groups references. I have been looking into refreshing the state, but this isn't working as it seems only one of the six groups is updated. I have tried also letting the client win. I really just need some guidance and tips on resolving this issue!

Here is my current code in my controller:

```
var group = _context.TherapyGroups.Include(r => r.Residents)
                                              .Where(x => x.ID.ToString() == groupid).FirstOrDefault();
            if(group == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            group.Residents.Clear();
            foreach(var id in residents)
            {
                var resident = _context.Residents.Where(x => x.ID.ToString() == id).FirstOrDefault();
                if(resident == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                }
                group.Residents.Add(resident);
            }
            bool saveFailed;
            do
            {
                saveFailed = false;
                try
                {

                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateException e)
                {
                    saveFailed = true;
                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, _context.Residents);
                }
            } while (saveFailed);
```

Comment: Just noticed I was refreshing _context.Residents. I have changed to refreshing _context.TherapyGroups and it still isn't working.

Comment: Rather than saving once the list of residents is complete, why not save after each resident is added to the list? Also, are you  using IoC containers to resolve the _context?

Comment: I am not using IoC right now.. Do you have something pointing me to the benefits of this?

Comment: No, no need, it was just to guide me as to where the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't sure how to fix the issue you are having with the code you have, so tried simplifying it a bit. See if this helps:

```
  var groupId = _context.TherapyGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToString() == groupid).Select(x => x.ID);

  if(groupId == "") // or if(groupId == 0), not sure type of x.ID
  {
      throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
  }

  // Get all of the residents whose Id is in the residents list
  var residentObjects = _context.Residents.Where(x => residents.Contains( x.ID.ToString()));

  // Update the groupId for each resident
  foreach(var resident in residentObjects)
  {
       resident.GroupId = groupId;
  }

  var saveFailed = false;
  try
  {
       _context.SaveChanges();
  }
  catch (DbUpdateException e)
  {
       saveFailed = true;
  }
```